# Is a X509 certificate in DER format ASN1 encoded?

Tags: c++, c, openssl, certificate, x509

I'm using OpenSSl to encrypt and decrypt files based on CMS/SMIME. Normally I load certificates with `rcert = PEM_read_bio_X509(tbio, NULL, 0, NULL);` but this is only for PEM formatted files I guess. I haven't found any `der.h` header or something similar.

So is there a way in OpenSSL to load DER formatted certificates? I've found the load function for `ASN1` format which uses OpenSSL intern.

```
if  (format == FORMAT_ASN1)
        x=d2i_X509_bio(cert,NULL);
```

But can that be used for DER which is binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DER is indeed encoded using ASN.1, and the `d2i_*()` family of functions is the way to load a DER file.