# how to programatically in C hash a X509 certificate in PEM format

Tags: c, hash, openssl, certificate, x509

I have generated a `X509` certificate in `DER` format, which is stored in a file with the name `cert.crt`.

I would like to be able to hash it with `sha256` algorithm.

How can this be done ?

I already have a function that allows me to hash any buffer of data, but I have the certificate in a file. Is there an easy way to do this ?

I am looking for a C implementation.

Comment: Topic says PEM, but question text says DER. Which format is it?

Comment: Why would you need to hash a certificate? Certificate already has a signature that includes a hash. If you need certificate validation, then it's much more complicated process than just "hashing a certificate".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at functions `fopen`and `fread`, they will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://linux.die.net/man/3/pem_read_x509 or http://linux.die.net/man/3/d2i_x509_fp can help you. Though the SSL man pages are terse, to put it nicely. In case the documentation fails, look for examples in the openssl utilitys source code.

**Edit** Also look at other SO answers, e.g. [Extract pem certificate information programmatically using openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509189/extract-pem-certificate-information-programmatically-using-openssl) and [Is a X509 certificate in DER format ASN1 encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499670/is-a-x509-certificate-in-der-format-asn1-encoded)

Answer (score 0):

For counting fingerprint hash of a PEM certificate file:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(pem_file_path, "r");
if (fp)
{
    X509 *x509 = PEM_read_X509(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (x509)
    {
        unsigned char md[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
        
        if (X509_digest(x509, EVP_sha256(), md, NULL) == 1)
        {
            // ok
        }
        
        X509_free(x509);
    }   
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Result should be same as with command:

```
openssl x509 -in my.pem -noout -fingerprint -sha256
```

For changing the hash algorithm just change `EVP_sha256()` by `EVP_sha512()`, `EVP_sha1()` etc...