# OpenSsl cannot read DER formatted certificate

Tags: c++, openssl, pem, der, asn.1

**Update**

I have based my solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499670/is-a-x509-certificate-in-der-format-asn1-encoded) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327299/parse-der-x509-in-c-or-c) answers.

**Background**

I am trying to read a DER formatted certificate file and attempt to verify it.

My cert is in `DER` format. I have confirmed this by:

Using `openssl` command line:

- `openssl x509 -text -noout -inform DER -in Cert.cer`: displays certificate
- `openssl x509 -text -noout -in Cert.cer`: displays `unable to load certificate`
- `openssl x509 -inform der -in Cert.cer -out Cert.pem`: converts DER to PEM

I am using the below code to read:

```
static std::vector<char> ReadAllBytes(char const* filename)
{
    std::cout << "in ReadAllBytes(" << filename << ")" << std::endl;
    std::ifstream stream(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<char> contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    std::cout << "out ReadAllBytes" << std::endl;

    return contents;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    auto readBytes = ReadAllBytes("Cert.cer");
    std::cout << "after ReadAllBytes, read size:" << readBytes.size() << std::endl;
    BIO *bio_mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_puts(bio_mem, readBytes.data());
    X509 * x509 = d2i_X509_bio(bio_mem, NULL);

    // PEM format
    //X509 *x509 = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio_mem, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if(x509 == NULL){
        unsigned int errCode = ERR_get_error();

        printf("\nError: %s\n", ERR_error_string(errCode, NULL));
        printf("\nLib: %s\n", ERR_lib_error_string(errCode));
        printf("\nFunc: %s\n", ERR_func_error_string(errCode));
        printf("\nReason: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(errCode));
    }

    BIO_free(bio_mem);
    X509_free(x509);
}
```

The output:

```
in ReadAllBytes(Cert.cer)
out ReadAllBytes
after ReadAllBytes, read size:1033

Error: error:0D06B08E:lib(13):func(107):reason(142)

Lib: (null)

Func: (null)

Reason: (null)
```

Updated output after calling `ERR_load_crypto_strings();`:

```
Error: error:0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO:not enough data

Lib: asn1 encoding routines

Func: ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO

Reason: not enough data
```

**Issue**

`d2i_X509_bio(bio_mem, NULL)` returns `NULL`.

I have successfully read the PEM formatted cert after converting with: `X509 *x509 = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio_mem, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

**Questions**

- Is there something wrong in my code that I have missed?
- How can I read a `DER` formatted x509 certificate file with openssl?

Comment: i don't know why you're jumping through hoops with the memory bio, and `BIO_puts` looks completely inappropriate to that note. Why aren't you just using `d2i_x509_fp` against a `FILE*` returned from `fopen` ?

Comment: To not have just the error code given by `ERR_error_string()` It seems you have to call  `ERR_load_crypto_strings();` ("The OpenSSL error strings should be loaded by calling ERR_load_crypto_strings or, for SSL applications, SSL_load_error_strings first. If there is no text string registered for the given error code, the error string will contain the numeric code." from https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/ERR_error_string.html )

Comment: Please see my update. Could you give a more detail on memory bio and `BIO_puts`? I am a little lost. As for `FILE*` and `d2i_x509_fp`, I will give it a try. But I don't see how it helps, I already have file bytes.

Comment: You probably need to rewind the BIO_MEM to 0 after writing to it; you're likely just sitting at the end of the data.

Comment: @bartonjs Any idea on how to rewind `BIO_MEM` without destroying its contents? [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html) states similar thing under **BUG**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you passed a data blob as a string.

`BIO_puts` (put string) copies up to the first zero-valued byte. Odds are this is somewhere in the middle of your certificate, which is why you're getting "not enough data" (a DER length value ends up being bigger than the length of the BIO data). (If your certificate had no zeros then it'll read too far and copy too much; be *really* careful calling functions that take pointers but not length).

`BIO_write`, on the other hand, writes the specified amount of data.

So instead of `BIO_puts(bio_mem, readBytes.data())` you want `BIO_write(bio_mem, readBytes.data(), readBytes.size())`.

Technically, you should write to `BIO_write` in a loop, checking the return value (how many bytes it accepted for write), but the `BIO_MEM` always either critically fails or succeeds in one call.

(It turns out that BIO_MEM isn't a stream (a data segment with a position) but a pipe (a data segment with a read position and a write position), so it doesn't need to be rewound after writing to it.)